# Dynamically populate <ul> from ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a webpage with a menu to skip to different sections using their ID's. I'd like to pull these ID's to dynamically create the navigation. I'm using jQuery elsewhere, but Vanilla JS is also an option.

So something like this:

```
<section id="foo">
   <h2>Foo</h2>
   ...
</section>
<section id="bar">
    <h2>Bar</h2>
    ...
</section>
```

Would result in the creation of this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: do you want to toggle sections from nav?

Comment: Post the JavaScript you tried that isn't working please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with jQuery, with an attempt to break the task down and make it easy to follow;

```js
$(function() {
  //call the fancy function on page-ready
  generatenav().appendTo($("div"));
});

function generatenav() {
  var $sections = $("section"); //get the sections
  var $nav = $("<nav>"); //create the nav
  var $ul = $("<ul>"); //create the list
  $ul.appendTo($nav);
  $.each($sections, function(idx, elem) { //loop through the sections
    let $li = $("<li>"); //create the li-element
    $li.append(
      $("<a>")  //create the anchor
        .attr("href", `#${$(elem).attr("id")}`) //set the href
        .text($(elem).find("h2:first-child").text())) //set the text
        .appendTo($ul);
  });
  return $nav;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<section id="foo">
  <h2>Foo</h2>
  ...
</section>
<section id="bar">
  <h2>Bar</h2>
  ...
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers! It looks like everyone's solution would have worked, but I can follow this solution and make modifications much easier given the comments and my greater familiarity with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Take the sections or element which you want to include it inside the nav. After that get the id and append inside the ul.

```
//iterate with tag name or assign some class
$('section').each(function(key, element){
   var elementID = element.attr('id');
   $('nav ul').append('<li><a href="#'+elementID+'"></a></li>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML you've shown, here's a plain easy vanilla JS solution:

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section[id]');
const nav = document.createElement('nav');
const ul = document.createElement('ul');
for (const section of sections) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = "#" + section.id;
  a.textContent = section.querySelector('h2').textContent;
  li.appendChild(a);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
nav.appendChild(ul);
header.appendChild(nav);
```

```css
#header nav { background: #f8f8f8; padding: 5px; }
#header ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#header li { margin: 0; padding: 0 20px; display: inline-block; }
#header a { color: #666; text-decoration: none; }
```

```html
<header id="header"></header>
<section id="foo">
  <h2>Foo</h2>
  ...
</section>
<section id="bar">
  <h2>Bar</h2>
  ...
</section>
<section id="baz">
  <h2>Baz</h2>
  ...
</section>
<section id="foobar">
  <h2>Foobar</h2>
  ...
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this with Vanilla JS:

```js
// Select all sections with IDs
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section[id]');

for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
  // Get the current section
  var section = sections[i];
  // Get the title inside that current section
  var title = section.querySelector('h2');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', '#' + section.id);
  var text = document.createTextNode(title.textContent);
  a.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(a);
  document.querySelector('nav ul').appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul></ul>
</nav>

<section id="foo">
  <h2>Foo</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam varius pulvinar mattis. Sed nec dui magna. Etiam elementum pellentesque mollis. Vestibulum varius, nulla et mattis imperdiet, quam nisi laoreet erat, eu tempus erat ex mollis nibh. Donec
    imperdiet lobortis diam, sed suscipit felis vestibulum id. Vestibulum tincidunt gravida augue nec convallis. Duis vel euismod urna. Aliquam porttitor, justo eget malesuada vestibulum, tellus nunc posuere libero, non facilisis enim sem quis tortor.
    Vivamus mollis luctus placerat. Phasellus sed lorem velit. Sed sit amet erat sit amet metus semper ullamcorper. Maecenas non erat ut mi ullamcorper tempor ut vitae tellus.</p>
</section>

<section id="bar">
  <h2>Bar</h2>
  <p>Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse condimentum vel tellus scelerisque pretium. Cras a hendrerit nisl. Quisque ornare ante eget lorem malesuada interdum. Aliquam augue est, imperdiet eu
    est non, dictum volutpat ligula. Ut sed feugiat eros, id euismod risus. Vestibulum vel libero sit amet lorem eleifend varius. Aenean eu ultricies augue, a tempus lorem. Quisque nisl dolor, commodo nec fringilla non, fringilla sed erat. Fusce vitae
    rhoncus turpis, eget vestibulum dui. Quisque tempor magna luctus urna viverra fermentum. Aliquam accumsan sodales ligula, viverra rutrum diam tempus vitae. Vestibulum sem diam, laoreet at vulputate id, tristique nec mauris.
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: How do you know the page has no `h2` outside of `section`, and that each `section` does contain only one `h2`?

Comment: You have to adapt your selectors to your page structure, I am proposing a solution according to the HTML given.

Comment: IE 11 does not support `forEach` on `NodeList`.

Comment: And what if any of the sections does not have an `id`?

Comment: You are right about IE11 support, it's fixed :) Thanks